# Numerical optimization in python: solution partly wiggly and large error

Tags: numerical-optimization, optimal-control, python

Let $T = \{0,1,\ldots, N-1\}$.
Consider the following problem:
\begin{align}
&\min_{(x(t))_{t \in T}}-\sum_{t \in T}{\beta^t \ln(x(t))}\\
\text{s.t.} \quad &\sum_{t \in T}{x(t)} = 1
\end{align}
where $\beta \in (0,1)$.
It's straightforward to show that the optimal solution is given by
\begin{align}
x^*(t) = \beta^t\frac{1-\beta}{1-\beta^N}.
\end{align}

I tried to solve the problem numerically, but it gives me a weird behaved solution.
Here is the python code:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from math import log

N = 200
T = range(N)
b = 0.95

obj = lambda x: -sum(b**t * log(x[t]) for t in T)
bnds = tuple((1e-10, None) for t in T)
cons = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x:  sum(x[t] for t in T) - 1}
x0 = tuple(1/N for t in T)
res = minimize(obj, x0, method='SLSQP', bounds=bnds, constraints=cons)

x_sol = res.x
x_star = [b**t * (1-b) / (1-b**N) for t in T]
```

Below you find a picture of the true solution and the numerical one.
As one can see, it is not a very good fit.
Especially around $t \in [60,100]$ it's getting all wiggly.

[image]

Let me also show the error below.
I think the error is quite bad.

[image]

- How would I smooth out the solution and increase the accurancy?

Comment: Heuristically, adding a smoothing term $(x(t_i)-x(t_{i+1}))^2$ will help, but you should first try and understand of the source of the instability is inherent, or a bug. I suppose that if the optimizer does not understand that perturbations in small $x$ are not linear, it will have problems converging (the error term of $log(x)$ is $O({1\over x})$).

Comment: There should not be a bug, because I can also find smooth solutions with 0 error over the entire time frame by varying $N$ or $\beta$ for instance. I also solved the problem via model predictive control and got very smooth results. I'm just a bit confused that the solver returns such a bad approximation of the true solution.

Comment: I suspect that some iterations drive $x<0$ which confuses the optimizer.

Comment: Does it do work properly when using a smaller N, say 20?

Comment: Yes. Here, in fact it raises the error that $x$ is sometimes below zero.

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid using bounds and constraints with scipy as they can result is failry bad fits.

In your example you can avoid the bounds $x\ge0$ by taking absolute value in your objective function. You can avoid the sum constraint by normalizing your input. Plus if you add some numpy vectorization to your code, you should end up with something similar to the below code, which produces much nicer fit.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from math import log
import numpy as np

N = 200
b = 0.95
w = np.array([b**t for t in range(N)]).T

obj = lambda x: -np.dot(w, np.log(abs(x) / sum(abs(x))))
x0 = np.random.rand(N) + 1
options = dict() # it's worth to play around with options
res = minimize(obj, x0, method='SLSQP', options=options)

x_sol = abs(res.x) / sum([abs(s) for s in res.x])
x_star = np.array([b**t * (1-b) / (1-b**N) for t in range(N)])
xx = range(len(x_star))

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(xx, x_star, xx, x_sol)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

your parameters return the message:

```
res['message']
'Iteration limit exceeded'
```

Increasing the iterations didn't help much, but
after some trial and error, I found that setting:

```
bnds = tuple((1e-10, 10) for t in T)
res = minimize(obj, x0, method='SLSQP', bounds=bnds, constraints=cons, options={'ftol':1e-7, 'maxiter': 1000})
```

seems to work nicely.
I have no idea why the optimizer is so finicky.
[image: plt.figure();plt.plot(res.x)]